# Unittest-TestSequenceFunctions is not defined

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(unittest.TestSequenceFunctions)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

And I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_CGSSv00.py", line 109, in <module>
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSequenceFunctions)
NameError: name 'TestSequenceFunctions' is not defined
```

Why is `TestSequenceFunctions` not defined?

Comment: I realized that Anaconda may be effecting unittest.  This may be the source of my problem, but I still don't know how to fix it if it is.

Comment: The answer is not to use TestSequenceFunctions but to use the class name of the test (e.g., 'CGSS' from 'class CGSS(unittest.TestCase)'